# How to avoid 1.23 decimal point uneven unit value in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I drag the icon to left and to right in paragraph panel of Photoshop for tweaking the paragraph styling, changing the value of space before and after paragraph, I get uneven unit value like 1.23 with decimal point. This is really annoyed to me. Do you know how to turn it off so it will get, for examples, 1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30 values only?

[image]

And is there a shortcut to change the value to 5px, 10px, 20px, etc...?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe you can turn this off.

As for the shortcut, you can get increments of .5 when you set your cursor in the box and then hit "shift" + up-arrow

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand why the increments is only .5. It seems to be useless in most of case.

Comment: I didn't program photoshop that way. You could leave feedback about this matter here: http://feedback.photoshop.com/